# Как исполнить скрипт при запуске docker-контейнера?

Tags: bash, docker

Здравствуйте!

Вопрос, возможно, несколько избит, но ответа на него я не нашел. А похожие вопросы на тостере, как в и гугле не помогли. 
Я буду премного благодарен тем людям, что уделят немного своего времени и дадут развернутый ответ!

И так, задача минимум - запустить apache при старте контейнера

Задача максимум - выполнить bash скрипт при старте контейнера

Я опишу варианты которые я пробовал.

**1. Сборка простейшего образа и запуск контейнера из консоли**

Dockerfile
    FROM ubuntu:14.04

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2
```

В консоли:
    sudo docker build -t apache .
    sudo docker run -dit --name cont_apache apache /bin/bash service   apache2 start

В ответ код контейнера, docker ps чист. docker logs cont_apache сообщает о запуске апача - Starting web server apache2 ...
Но сам контейнер почему-то умирает. хотя флаг -d установлен.

Попытался:
    sudo docker run -dit --name cont_apache apache service apache2 start

Результат точно такой же.

**2. Сборка образа и запуск апача при помощи CMD**

Dockerfile:
    FROM ubuntu:14.04

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2

CMD ["service" "apache2", "start"]
```

В консоли:
    sudo docker build -t apache .
    sudo docker run -dit --name cont_apache apache /bin/bash service apache2 start

Контейнер запущем, висит как демон, перехожу в контейнер:
root@2a97628fd78b:/# service apache2 status
* apache2 is not running
Апач не запустился.
Почему?

**3. Сборка образа с проброской bash скрипта и его выполнение**

Dockerfile:
    FROM ubuntu:14.04

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 

COPY ./apache2_start.sh /root/apache2_start.sh

CMD ["chmod", "777", "/root/apache2_start.sh"]

CMD ["/root/apache2_start.sh"]
```

Script apache2_start.sh:
    #!/bin/bash

```
service apache2 start
echo "127.0.0.1"
```

В консоли:
    sudo docker build -t apache .
    sudo docker run -dit --name cont_apache apache

В docker ps контейнера нет. В логах docker logs cont_apache:
     * Starting web server apache2                                                  AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
     * 
    127.0.0.1

Пробовал также с запуском bash из консоли:
    sudo docker run -dit --name cont_apache apache /bin/bash

В результате контейнер висит в docker ps. Docker logs conf_apache чист.

А в самом контейнере:
    root@d2c9831773a9:/# service apache2 status
    * apache2 is not running

Итог.

Я попытался добиться нужного результата разными способами, но ни одним у меня не вышло.

Очевидно, что я допускаю ошибки в работе с докером.

Я буду очень! благодарен за конструктивную помощь в данном вопросе как в целом, так и что в каком конкретном случае я делал не так.

Конечно, эти примеры высосаны из пальца, и можно найти кучу примеров запуска окружения при помощи docker compose. Но моя цель разобраться в вопросе, и уже в дальнейшем использовать всякие крутые штуки вроде docker compose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Докер-контейнер - это один процесс, обернутый в изолированную среду. Этот процесс может порождать дочерние процессы, но основной постулат остается одинаковым: время жизни контейнера - это время жизни процесса, указанного в ENTRYPOINT/CMD. Насколько понимаю, команда `apache2 service start` попытается запустить апач в фоновом режиме и тут же закончит свое выполнение; как только докер увидит, что процесс закончился, он прибьет контейнер. Таким образом, ваша конечная цель - выполнить в начале скрипта требуемые действия, а потом сделать так, чтобы он выполнялся все время жизни приложения (в случае с апачем - условно бесконечно). Проще всего это сделать следующим образом:

- выполнить требуемые действия
- последней командой в шелл-скрипте запустить апач с отключенным фоновым режимом ([-DFOREGROUND](http://zroger.com/blog/apache-in-the-foreground/)), предварив команду инструкцией `exec`. Эта инструкция позволит текущему процессу (выполняющемуся шелл-скрипту) стать процессом, вызванным exec. После этого ctrl-c и прочие плюшки будут отправляться на обработку напрямую апачу.

пример такой работы можно увидеть прямо в [официальном изображении library](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/httpd-foreground)

Comment: запуск апача с -DFOREGROUND решил эту проблему. Но не отрабатывает команда CMD  ["chmod", "777", "/root/apache2_start.sh"]. Я попробовал перенести ее в apache_start.sh - chmod 777 /root/apache2_start.sh, в этом случае права на файл меняются. Вы можете подсказать почему CMD не срабатывает?

Comment: @Victor я же написал - команда отрабатывает, скрипт завершается, контейнер прибивается

Comment: Вы меня, видимо, не правильно поняли. При запуске контейнера в нем крутится апач, все верно. docker ps видит его как запущенный. Я подключаюсь в этому контейнеру, docker exec, и проверяю права на файл /root/apache2_start.sh. Они установленны в 755, хотя, как я понимаю, у этого файла должны быть установленны права 777, так как в докер файла есть команда CMD ["chmod", "777", "/root/apache2_start.sh"]. Так во мне не понятно почему не сработала именно эта команда CMD ["chmod", "777", "/root/apache2_start.sh"].

Comment: Потому что CMD - это точка запуска, и либо у вас выполняется только chmod, либо только что-то другое. Скорее всего, вы путаете с RUN. Кроме того, chmod вам вообще не нужен, потому что в контейнере только один пользователь.

Comment: Действительно! Перенес в RUN и все заработало. Chmod я привел для краткости для описания проблемы. У меня там было еще несколько команд) Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Если уже есть подходящий официальный image, то лучше использовать его, а не брать ubuntu и туда делать `apt-get install`.

Для Apache: https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/

Можно сделать свой image, который наследуется от него, а можно запускать его напрямую.

Вероятно, нужен ещё php. Для этого можно взять image `php:apache`
https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Если нужны ещё другие приложения, например, [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), то по идеологии Docker надо запускать их в отдельном контейнере.

Answer (score 1):

По идеологии docker запустить bash скрипт при старте контейнера не получится, т.к. в нем не обрабатывается init как в хостовой машине. Для автозапуска процессов нужно использовать DockerFile с указанными в директиве CMD процессами.

 Или можно сделать следующим образом: run контейнера делать с ключом --restart unless-stopped, тогда контейнер будет стартовать при запуске системы. А для запуска процессов в контейнере написать простой баш скрипт на хостовой машине вроде этого:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker exec  <containerID> service nginx start
sudo docker exec  <containerID> service php7.2-fpm start
sudo docker exec  <containerID> service mysql start
```

Стартует nginx, php-fpm и mysql в указанном контейнере. Можно добавить своего пользователя в группу docker для исключения "sudo" и поставить скрипт в автозапуск init хостовой машины