# Как запустить скрипт после запуска контейнера в docker

Tags: linux, docker

Есть некий скрипт который должен запускаться после создания контейнера

Dockerfile

```
FROM someimage
MAINTAINER Meiram
RUN /somedir/somescript.sh start
```

В итоге после билда образа
Создаю контейнер

```
$ docker run -td newsomeimage
```

В итоге процесс не запущен, а он должен быть всегда запущен.

---

Данный скрипт запускается с параметром start, он слушает нужный ему порт. Он должен быть всегда запущен. Необходимо после рестарта контейнера или ребута хоста не вмешиваться в работу контейнера.

На данный момент после каждого старта контейнера я вручную захожу на контейнер с помощью директивы `docker exec`, и вручную запускаю скрипт, но это не совсем то, что хотелось бы. Есть ли другие способы запускать скрипт постоянно после старта контейнера?

Comment: дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/519676/16095

Answer (score 2):

**исправлено**:

директива `run` в `dockerfile` задаёт команду(-ы), которые выполняются на этапе создания образа.

для указания команды, которая будет выполняться при запуске контейнера, следует использовать [директиву `cmd`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). например:

```
cmd /somedir/somescript.sh start
```

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!
Данный скрипт запускается с параметром start который слушает нужный ему порт. Он должен быть всегда запущен.

Необходимо после рестарта контейнера или ребута хоста не вмешиваться в работу контейнера. 

На данный момент после каждого старта контейнера я вручную захожу на контейнер с помощью директивы docker exec и вручную запускаю скрип, но это не совсем то, что хотелось бы. 

Есть ли другие способы запускать скрипт постоянно после старта контейнера?

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev, я исправил ответ. предыдущий вариант был неверен, прошу прощения.

Comment: Александр, к сожалению ваш вариант не работает. Добавлял CMD с параметрами. В итоге при старте контейнера скрип запускается но со статусом exited.

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev, я думаю, вам лучше задать новый вопрос, в котором привести **полное** содержимое вашего dockerfile и скрипта, который вы упоминаете. и вывод `docker inspect` для созданного вами образа.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал через supervisord

через документацию https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/

Дело в том, что процесс у меня крашился если не соединялся с другим сервисом.